# Moving Player depending on user input

Tags: java, android, image, libgdx, move

I want to make the player (Actually just an image) move position in a 2D "game" depending on where the user presses the screen (Android).

This is my code:

```
   public void updateState(float delta) {
        if(Gdx.input.isButtonPressed(Buttons.LEFT)){
             if(Gdx.input.getX()>player.getX()+5) {
                  player.setX(player.getX()+5);
             }else if (Gdx.input.getX()<player.getX()-5){
                  player.setX(player.getX()-5);
             }
             if(Gdx.input.getY()>player.getY()+5){
                  player.setY(player.getY() + 5);
             }else if(Gdx.input.getY()<player.getY()-5){
                  player.setY(player.getY()-5);
             }
             return;
        }
   }
```

Sometimes, when I press on the right part, it goes to the right (as expected), others it goes to the left (No idea why). Same happens with every other direction.

What is the problem in my code?

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:** Before anyone tells me this, yes, I know I should be using delta (time elapsed since last render) to calculate the movement, I will when i figure this out. :)

Comment: You should print the values of "Gdx.input.getX()" and "player.getX()" , to find out why .

Comment: Wow, thats actually so simple that I feel dumb because I did not realise. Thanks, will try tonight and will update if I keep being dumb.

Comment: Have you tried debugging it in some way?  ie have it tell you the coordinates of the player and of the input, or try setting the location of the image to the input position

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delete that return. Does nothing:

```
public void updateState(float delta) {
    if(Gdx.input.isButtonPressed(Buttons.LEFT)){

        if(Gdx.input.getX()>player.getX()) {
            player.setX(player.getX()+5);
        }else if (Gdx.input.getX()<player.getX()){
            player.setX(player.getX()-5);
        }
        if(Gdx.graphics.getHeight()-Gdx.input.getY()>player.getY()){
            player.setY(player.getY() + 5);
        }else if(Gdx.graphics.getHeight()-Gdx.input.getY()<player.getY()){
            player.setY(player.getY()-5);
        }
    }
}
```